# Avoiding a Header conflict in php, after creating a session from logging in?

Tags: php, mysql, html, session, authentication

Today I learned for the first time how to create a simple login system (with thanks StackExchange tips and [THIS TUTORIAL](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL).   What i'm trying to do is use the [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) framework to generate an Excel file ONLY for those who successfully login.

I've gotten very close, however I'm getting a crazy message about headers and below that is a bunch of jargon mixed up text.

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at     /home3/mydir/public_html/d23/members/loggedin.php:6) in     /home3/mydir/public_html/d23/members/create_excel.php on line 92

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at      /home3/mydir/public_html/d23/members/loggedin.php:6) in     /home3/mydir/public_html/d23/members/create_excel on line 93

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/mydir/public_html/d23/members/loggedin.php:6) in /home3/mydir/public_html/d23/members/create_excel on line 94
ÐÏà¡±á;þÿ       þÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
```

I know that the error is coming from these lines in the "create_excel.php" file, because when I comment them out, there is no error.  But there is also no excel file creation.

```
 header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="userList.xls"');
 header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

I will outline my process step by step- i'm a beginner so I bet this is stupidly easy for someone.

**STEP #1  (login.php)**

Calls the "process_login.php" file to authenticate the password typed into the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Login Please</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="process_login.php" method="post">
Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**PAGE 2  (process_login.php)**

If everything is fine,it will now re-direct you to "logged_in.php", if not- you will get a denied message.

```
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($database);


//$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$username = "person";
$password = hash('sha512', $_POST['password']);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE password = '$password'
");


if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{
  // Login
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['username'] = htmlspecialchars($username); // htmlspecialchars() sanitises     XSS
  // Redirect
header('Location: loggedin.php');
exit;
}
else
{
  echo '<p><strong>Error:</strong> Invalid username or password.</p>';
}
?>
```

**STEP 3  (logged_in.php)**

Now we have been successfully logged in, with an approval notice as well as a request to run "create_excel.php" file.

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
  // Logged in
  echo '<p>You are logged in as '. $_SESSION['username']. '.</p>';
   // require the PHPExcel file
require 'create_excel.php';

}
else
{
  // Not logged in
  echo '<p>You are not <a href="login.php">logged in</a>.</p>';
}
?>
```

**STEP #4  (create_excel.php)**

This is where the header problem happens.  I've tried to put the session script on this page alone, but I get the same problem.  I was thinking if it was pulled from the "logged_in" page everything would be fine- but no.  (Currently if I access this page directly the Excel file is generated and downloaded no problem).

```
<?php
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

/** PHPExcel */
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';


// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten     Balliauw")
                             ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test     Document")
                             ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test     Document")
                             ->setDescription("Test document for         Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
                             ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml     php")
                             ->setCategory("Test result file");


// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
            ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');

// Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A4', 'Miscellaneous glyphs')
            ->setCellValue('A5', 'éàèùâêîôûëïüÿäöüç');

// Rename sheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');


// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Comment: The actual error line in this example is not totally correct because i used another example (create_excel) file as to not show personal details.  But I know the error is coming 3 lines of code, will post an edit right now.

Comment: one thing i can suggest is instead of echoing values every time you can append the string to a variable, and echo it at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  echo '<p>You are logged in as '. $_SESSION['username']. '.</p>';
  // require the PHPExcel file
  require 'create_excel.php';
```

There lies your problem. You're sending output to the client and then you want to change the headers and do something else. It doesn't work that way.

Consider doing it like this:

```
  echo '<p>You are logged in as '. $_SESSION['username']. '.</p>';
   // link to the PXPExcel file
  echo '<a href=\'create_excel.php\'>To Excel!</a>';
```

Or just output the excel file without the login message:

```
  require 'create_excel.php';
```

Comment: This is actually what I would like to do the most- (having a link to the file output).  I just did what you mentioned, but the problem is that link could be shared and anyone would be able to access "create_excel.php"

Comment: You can apply the same logic you used on your logged_in.php page. Meaning, check if the user is logged in ( you check if the $_SESSION['username'] excists, if so, execute your Excel generating code, otherwise, don't do anything / redirect the user to your login page.

Comment: Perfect- the problem was having the headers in the "create_excel" file below everything else.  Now they are at the top (just inside the conditional and it's perfect!)

Answer (score 2):

In your `logged_in.php` you echo the following:

```
echo '<p>You are logged in as '. $_SESSION['username']. '.</p>';
```

after wards you include `create_excel.php`, where you try to modify the header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

But if you want to modify the header it has to be done first! If you output anything else you'll get an error while trying to modify the header...

Comment: So technically I could take that header information out of the "create_excel.php" file, and place it into "logged_in.php", as long as it is ABOVE my echo statement?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is some output before you set the headers. There should be no output before sending out headers.

Even a blank line can produce this error.

In your script you include loggedinn.php and taht file echoes some string. This causes the error you are getting.

php `header()` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) clearly states.

> Remember that header() must be called
> before any actual output is sent,
> either by normal HTML tags, blank
> lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a
> very common error to read code with
> include(), or require(), functions, or
> another file access function, and have
> spaces or empty lines that are output
> before header() is called. The same
> problem exists when using a single
> PHP/HTML file.

The easiest way to prevent this is for you to redirect users not logged in to a login page. At the very least you should not continue with your excel creating code if the user is not logged in.